# Using concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor with DataFrame.GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, pandas-groupby, python-multiprocessing

This might be a common problem, but I failed to find any good / up-to-date solutions online. I am currently working on a huge dataframe for n companies, whereby we do some heavy calculations per company an then aggregate all the results as a new dataframe. Pretty straightforward, we run `df.groupby('company').apply(function)` and go grab a cup of coffee while it runs, since this is a single threaded operations.

Now things are getting out of control, with (3h+ wait time), and we're experimenting with multiprocessing. We have implemented the small 'concept' below, whereby we pass a DataFrame.GroupBy to the executor.map callback function and wait for the results.

Problem is, it seems to take a veeeeeeery long time to run, with no feedback on what is actually happening inside each thread. Not sure this is the correct implementation, all I can see is CPU and memory running at 100% use, but the executor never finishes.

Below is a simplified version of the calculations to be done for every company in the database. Advise on how to properly use groupby with multiprocessing is much appreciated.

```
import time
import concurrent

def append_new_company_technicals(group):
    '''
    Takes a dataframe and build new columns with technical information
    '''
    print(group['ticker'].unique())
    group.sort_values(by='date', inplace=True)

    group['halfvol_30_abs'] = group['px'].rolling(30,min_periods = 21).apply(func)
    group['halfvol_180_abs'] = group['px1'].rolling(180,min_periods = 135).apply(func)
    group['halfvol_30_rel'] = group['px2'].rolling(30,min_periods = 21).apply(func)
    group['halfvol_180_rel'] = group['px3'].rolling(180,min_periods = 135).apply(func)
    return group
    
start = time.time()
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    futures = {executor.map(append_new_company_technicals, df_merged.groupby('ticker'))}
end = time.time()
print("MultiProcessing computation: {} secs ".format(end - start))
```

Comment: You should probably look into using Dask, it is built for handling multicore/distributed compute on arrays and data frames.  It will handle your task much better than trying to roll your own implementation

Comment: We've checked Dask, Modin and Ray, but none would work without some significant code refactoring on our side... We're making one last attempt with pandas + python native multiprocessing, but you are probably right eventually we will need to migrate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some feedback as the thing is running try applying the tqdm function (from the tqdm package) to an iterable. In your case to df_merged.groupby('ticker').

Comment: I believe this should rather be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: You are probably right. I'm new where and can't post comments unfortunately.

Comment: Cool, never tried tqdm, thanks for the tip.